# How can I access the NSWindow CALayer?

Tags: swift, macos, animation, cocoa, core-animation

If we want to animate a window we can use `open func setFrame(_ frameRect: NSRect, display displayFlag: Bool, animate animateFlag: Bool)`. Or for more control we can use the same function inside an `NSAnimationContext` block. But none of those ways gives full control of animation like Core Animation gives.

I am not sure if this is a thing that we could access the window CALayer for adding our custom animation like we do for NSView. I am unable to find a property inside NSWindow for assigning the CALayer. I'm not sure if this functionality exists in a name other than a layer. Since mostly all the animations happens in view of SwiftUI, UIKit, Appkit or Cocoa are based on Core Animation, that would make sense that NSWindow frame animation based on Core Animation, but accessing it or updating it is my question.

Comment: `NSWindow` is not a view. It is more abstract than that. Its `contentView` is a view, and you can get its layer easily. Its title bar is also a view. They also have a common superview, but that, just like the title bar view, is a private class. You can get it just by going up the view hierarchy. Though I suspect whatever animation you are doing on it is probably going to be covered up by the content view's and title bar view's layers anyway. In any case, using private stuff like this is never a good idea in my experience.

Comment: I can access the contentView of window also the layer of it, but the window itself and the the contentView are deferent as you said, I can do anything to contentView because I have access the layer, but because I have no access to the layer of window I am limited just for the ways I mentioned in question.

Comment: Let me give more information, the try to access the layer of window is not going effect on the contentView of the window or any oder subViews that window has or not even title bar, the goal is animating the window frame itself with much more control via Core animation.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seems like `contentView.superview.layer` is actually nil. So "the layer of the window" isn't something that exists at all. You just have the layer of the title bar, and the layer of the content view. That's it. I suspect macOS animates both at the same time when you call something like `setFrame`.

Comment: I think you are right, apple just let us animate window frame itself just with `setFrame`, but I think this method should internally use Core Animation because we have nothing else than that for animation in this level of coding not sure about metal.

Comment: Another thing having the method of `setFrame` that we can set true for animation for window means apple does not want give us access to the layer of window itself, that is the why the `setFrame` exist with option of having animation for `setFrame`, there is no such function for NSView because we have full control on CALayer of NSView and existing such function for NSView it doesn't make sense.